# How to get IP address of MAAS machine by terraform output

Tags: terraform, devops, infrastructure-as-code, maas

I provision machine by terraform and maas but I can't get ip address of provided machine in

output of terraform.

I'm using of [suchpuppet](https://github.com/suchpuppet/terraform-provider-maas) as maas provider

for IaC but just returned machine_id and doesn't return IP address of it.
[image: Terraform code]

[image: output terraform]

In output returning machine_id instead of ip address of machine.

Comment: Please add some code so we know where to look and what the issue is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comment.

I resolve my problem by calling MAAS API and sending machine_id to MAAS API

and getting the IP address of the machine for use in the configuration manager

tools.

```
from oauthlib.oauth1 import SIGNATURE_PLAINTEXT # fades
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1Session # fades

MAAS_HOST = "URL_OF_MAAS"
CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_TOKEN, SECRET = "API_KEY_MAAS".split(":")

maas = OAuth1Session(CONSUMER_KEY, resource_owner_key=CONSUMER_TOKEN, 
resource_owner_secret=SECRET, signature_method=SIGNATURE_PLAINTEXT)

nodes = maas.get(f"{MAAS_HOST}/api/2.0/machines/gfppbc/")
nodes.raise_for_status()

print(nodes.json()['ip_addresses'][0])
```